# jQuery - How to add button close after retrieve data from Ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a problem with retrieve data from Ajax. I want to add button "X" to close popup after show data.

I tried to add a button like:

```
jQuery(".popup").append('<button style="font-size: 150%; color: red; top: 0; right: 0;">x</button>');
```

in to popup to the user can close my popup.

My code like:

```
function getData(domain){
    var dataString = "domain=" + domain + "&security="+ mhdomain.security + "&action=getdomain" ;
    jQuery.ajax({
        action: "getDomain",
        type: "post",
        url: mhdomain.ajaxurl,
        dataType: "json",
        data: dataString,
        beforeSend: function(xhr){
            jQuery("#wrapper").append('<div class="popup" onclick="popupout(\'.popup\')"></div>');
            jQuery(".popup").append("<img src='https://i.imgur.com/CH8XnNt.gif' alt='loading' />");  
            jQuery(".popup").fadeIn();
            jQuery(".popup").append('<button style="font-size: 150%; color: red; top: 0; right: 0;">x</button>');
        },
        success : function(data){
            jQuery(".popup").html(data.data);
        },
    });      
};
function popupout(popup){
    jQuery(popup).fadeOut(1000);
    jQuery(popup).remove();
}
```

My CSS code:

```
.popup {
    position: fixed;
    display: none;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    z-index: 99999;
    max-width: 780px;
    width: 100%;
    max-height: 480px;
    height: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: white;
    padding: 30px 50px;
    color: black;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    border: 1px solid #f2f2f2;
}
```

Comment: why don't you append your button in success?

Comment: yes, I was. I append into `success : function(data)` but don't have any button was show. I don't know the problem at here. I check element in HTML file but can't find element button was added before.

Comment: Is your popup class generate dynamically ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your `beforeSend` event you are appending the html which is fine. But it gets replaced in success event.
in this line the issue is

```
jQuery(".popup").html(data.data);
```

But instead of you just append data.data here also which will fix the issue. like this

```
jQuery(".popup").append(data.data);
```

---

For your question in comment, still you can use beforeSend event. Like this

```
beforeSend:function(){
// after your codes
jQuery(".popup").append("<img src='loading.gif' class='loading'>");
}

success:function(){
// after your codes
jQuery(".popup").find('.loading').remove();
}
```

You can tweak the appearance of the images using css. But I shared an idea for how to achieve that

Comment: if I have a image loading while wait data return. I want remove it and keep button close. Have method to do this? You can see my demo code have image loading. When show result should remove it.

Comment: Check my modified answer

Answer (score 1):

You can add your `close button` html in success.

```
 function getData(domain){
    var dataString = "domain=" + domain + "&security="+ mhdomain.security + "&action=getdomain" ;
    jQuery.ajax({
        action: "getDomain",
        type: "post",
        url: mhdomain.ajaxurl,
        dataType: "json",
        data: dataString,
        beforeSend: function(xhr){
            jQuery("#wrapper").append('<div class="popup" onclick="popupout(\'.popup\')"></div>');
            jQuery(".popup").append("<img src='https://i.imgur.com/CH8XnNt.gif' alt='loading' />");  
            jQuery(".popup").fadeIn();
            jQuery(".popup").append('<button style="font-size: 150%; color: red; top: 0; right: 0;">x</button>');
        },
        success : function(data){
            jQuery(".popup").html('<div class="popup" onclick="popupout(\'.popup\')"></div>'+data.data);
        },
    });      
};
function popupout(popup){
    jQuery(popup).fadeOut(1000);
    jQuery(popup).remove();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The close button is being overwritten by `jQuery(".popup").html(data.data);` because you are replacing everything inside of `.popup`.

I have some of your code in the snippet below using .append instead of .html and your button appears and it works.

I would just put a placeholder in the popup that houses the loading gif and replace that div's html with the data.

```js
function getData(){
    jQuery("#wrapper").append('<div class="popup" onclick="popupout(\'.popup\')"></div>');
    jQuery(".popup").append("<img src='https://i.imgur.com/CH8XnNt.gif' alt='loading' />");  
    jQuery(".popup").fadeIn();
    jQuery(".popup").append('<button style="font-size: 150%; color: red; top: 0; right: 0;">x</button>');

    jQuery(".popup").append('popup data');
   
};
function popupout(popup){
    jQuery(popup).fadeOut(1000);
    jQuery(popup).remove();
}

getData();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper" ></div>
```